# Blob error Laravel wrong or not

Tags: laravel, blob

I just saw that I have a problem of loading "blob" in my Laravel project. I don't know what it is, is it problem? Why are these messages?

[image]

Thanks you!

Comment: somewhere in the js code ('maybe vue components'), an element has the value as image blob not for example `http://example.com/image.jpg`, and i think it's considered as unsafe